# WCF Rest service endpoint not getting triggered when passing image over a certain size

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, rest

SUMMARY:  When an image exceeds a certain size, the endpoint on my REST service never triggers.

***Disclaimer:  I have looked at I think every single post on StackOverflow and google for that matter related to this topic.  Nothing I've tried has worked.***

I suspect I'm missing something due to sheer ignorance.  I'm relatively new to WCF.

What I've setup is the following:

1. REST service that exposes multiple endpoints to support image processing.
2. Everything is sent/returned as JSON

Here is a copy of my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ImgService.Service1">
        <endpoint 
        name="REST" 
        address="" 
            binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="ImgService.IDataService" 
        behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

This is what my endpoint looks like as defined in the service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/WarpImage",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    Method = "POST",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
ServiceResponse<DataContracts.PROCImgObject> WarpImage(DataContracts.PROCImgObject imgObject);
```

The PROCImgObject is defined as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class PROCImgObject : PROCServiceObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public System.Drawing.Point leftWaist { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public System.Drawing.Point rightWaist { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public System.Drawing.Point leftNavel { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public System.Drawing.Point rightNavel { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public System.Drawing.Point leftHips { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public System.Drawing.Point rightHips { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int BodyTypeID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public double WaistInInches { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Base64EncodedImageData { get; set; }

    public PROCImgObject()
    {
        Service1.writeMessage("Create image called");
    }
}
```

The bitmap data is base64 encoded and passed to the service as part of a JSON structure.

Now to test the failure I am making a call from an Android application I'm developing to test this with.  In order to test what size the image fails at, I started resizing the image in code.

Here is the Android code snippet to resize the image:

```
        PROCImgObject imgObj = new PROCImgObject();
        imgObj.BodyTypeID = 4;
        imgObj.WaistInInches = 40;
        Bitmap resized = ImageUtil.getResizedBitmap(mCurrentPicture.TheBitmap, 300, 300);
        int numberOfBytes = resized.getByteCount();
        String base64 = ImageUtil.encodeTobase64(resized);
        imgObj.Base64EncodedImageData = base64;

        warpService = new ServicePostWarpImage();
        warpService.execute(imgObj);
        warpService.delegate = SnapImage.this;
```

When I resize the bitmap to 255,255...the endpoint triggers and works fine.

When I resize the bitmap to 256,256...the endpoint never triggers and the code never fires.  I also don't receive any type of exception...is the service just rejecting the call due to the size of the base64Encoded string in the JSON structure?

I'd really apprecaite any insight/push in the right direction/suggestions on how to make the configuration and code better.

I'm somewhat new to WCF.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Damn it...this is the second time today I've answered my own question.  I don't know what it is...but I can research for hours and then when I post the question to SO, I figure it out.

Anyways...I was close.

It's all about the maxReceivedMessageSize.  The thing that pisses me off is I've been messing with that ALL NIGHT.  Grrrr...anyways it works.

Here's the updated binding:

I changed this:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

TO THIS (WTF):

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize = "1000000">
        <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Don't ask me why it works.  I just turned some knobs until I was successful. (shrug)